# Upgrading Mule runtime from 3.8.4 to 3.9.2 following issue related to dependency tanukisoft:wrapper:jar:3.5.35

Tags: mule, runtime

I am getting below error, while , Upgrading Muleruntime from 3.8.4 to 3.9.2 following issue related to dependency tanukisoft:wrapper:jar:3.5.35

Failed to collect dependencies at com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-boot-ee:jar:3.9.2 -> tanukisoft:wrapper:jar:3.5.35: Failed to read artifact descriptor for tanukisoft:wrapper:jar:3.5.35: Could not transfer artifact tanukisoft:wrapper:pom:3.5.35 from/to MuleRepository (https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/): Access denied to: https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/tanukisoft/wrapper/3.5.35/wrapper-3.5.35.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. ->

1. I have configured Server details in my settings.xml
2. I have configured Mule repository ( https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/)

Answer (score 0):

The credentials for MuleSoft’s Enterprise Repository (https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee) are incorrect or not set. Please review that you set the credentials correctly as [described in the documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb).

Example:

in your settings.xml there has to be an entry for the credentials that match the repository id used:

```
<servers>
...
    <server>

        <id>MuleRepository</id>
        <username>YOUR_ID</username>
        <password>YOUR_PASSWORD</password>

    </server>
...
</servers>
```

Unrelated to the issue, I strongly recommend to use 3.9.4, the latest patched version, as it contains much more fixes than 3.9.2.

Comment: I have added the required server details already. With those same credentials I can access both the below url's from browser                       https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/ and https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/tanukisoft/wrapper/3.5.35/wrapper-3.5.35.pom I am also able to download it from the browser required jar as well

Comment: Are you still having the issue? Try to execute Maven with the update flag in case the failure has been cached (mvn -U clean package). If that still fails try in debug mode (-X) and attach the new error (mvn -U -X clean package)

Comment: Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact tanukisoft:wrapper:pom:3.5.35 from/to MuleRepository (https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/): Access denied to: https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/tanukisoft/wrapper/3.5.35/wrapper-3.5.35.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportL

Comment: If I go and access this mulesoft repo from browser then it works fine.... but in Maven it fails with the above error.

Comment: The error says the reason: access denied. Something about the authentication is incorrect. Maybe the password is incorrect in settings.xml or the id of the repository is not matching between settings.xml and pom.xml